# Removing a gradle or groovy project configuration in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, gradle, eclipse-project-file

I imported some Eclipse projects and one is randomly got a Gr and the other a G on the icon for the project in the Navigator in Eclipse. If I right click on the project I see that I can configure these projects to Maven or Grails or Faceted Form. I want to remove these configurations entirely so that my Eclipse matches my coworker's Eclipse. We cannot figure out how to do this, any help?

Comment: Did you tried removing the facets?

Comment: Do you want to change the *project* to no longer be a maven/groovy/etc project, or do you mean you want to make your version of eclipse no longer support projects of that type?

Comment: Removing the project facets and digging around the right click menu some more fixed it. For Groovy I could remove the "Groovy Nature". For Gradle I had to remove the facet.

Comment: Did you used ```gradle cleanEclipse eclipse``` to setup the Eclipse project?